# What's the difference between 'useradd' and 'adduser'?

Tags: debian, user-accounts

What's the difference between `useradd` and `adduser`? When/why should I prefer using one or the other?

Comment: What operating system are you referring to?

Comment: Also - http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd

Comment: This is a **`Debian Linux`** based question.

Comment: Same question on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd/381646#381646) and on [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/547966/whats-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd).

Comment: if you're wondering how to _remember_ which one is the friendlier version, pick alphabetically: **a**dduser before **u**seradd

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the case of Debian and its related distros, adduser is a friendlier interactive frontend to useradd.

Comment: It is not about friendliness, it's about usage. You can use adduser for interactively adding an account or you can use useradd for batch adding accounts. useradd has also an interactive mode.

Comment: @tkorkunckaya: so what usage based on your description then if useradd can also do interactive mode?

Comment: useradd does not have an interactive mode

Answer (score 17):

**Always use `adduser`** (and `deluser` when deleting users).

The `useradd`, `userdel` and `usermod` commands are lowlevel utilities which are there for historical reasons, while `adduser/deluser` Do The Right Thing™. (I remember which to use by thinking that `user*` comes after `adduser/deluser` in the alphabet, and therefore is "worse".)

According to the respective manpages (on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin, i.e. a Debian derivative system).

### Manpage for `adduser` says:

(Emphasis added.)

> `adduser` and `addgroup` add users and groups to the system according to command line
>   options and configuration information in `/etc/adduser.conf`. **They are friendlier
>   front ends to the low level tools like `useradd`, `groupadd` and `usermod` programs**,
>   by default  choosing Debian policy conformant UID and GID values, creating a home
>   directory with skeletal configuration, running a custom script, and other features.
>   `adduser` and `addgroup` can be run in one of five modes:

### Manpage for `useradd` says:

> `useradd` is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should
>   usually use `adduser(8)` instead.

See also:

- [What's the difference between “adduser” and “useradd”?](https://superuser.com/q/547966/221259) (on SuperUser)
- [What is the difference between `adduser` and
  `useradd`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345974) (on Ask Ubuntu).

Comment: Agree with that, "Always use adduser" over useradd. This should be the accepted answer !

Answer (score 13):

On Ubuntu, useradd simply creates an entry in the user database (/etc/passwd etc.).

adduser on the other hand also creates a home directory for the user, populates it with the content of /etc/skel and lets you set the password interactively.

Comment: +1. man useradd : "useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead."

Comment: I believe adduser also interactively fills in the GECOS fields

Comment: @petrus why so?

Comment: useradd can create the home directory, set password, add to groups, create skeleton files and even set the shell.

Answer (score 8):

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Nov 17 13:52 /usr/sbin/adduser -> useradd

One is a "shortcut" / "symbolic link" to the other. So no difference.

This is on redhat linux (and centos / fedora), it may not hold true on other distros.

Comment: Correct on RH, but some dists such as ubuntu has different binaries.

Comment: True, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Many binaries and scripts alter their behavior based on the command line invocation.

Answer (score 7):

On FreeBSD:
`adduser` is a "friendly" interactive Q&A way to add local users.
`useradd` doesn't exist.